# Is it possible to define that AJAX-query has been executed (clear JS)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events, actionlistener

The problem is that I need to hide the some tag with specific class, and this content is dynamically generated via AJAX.

Without using jQuery or another libraries - is it possible to define that AJAX has been done, DOM-tree has been changed and need tag has appeared to find him via `getElementsByClassName` ?

Comment: Can you not hook into the `readystatechange` event fired by the `XMLHttpRequest` of the AJAX request in question?

Comment: Thanks for hint, really. Need to find more info about readystatechange.

Comment: Show us that ajax request, without code we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Why is need the ajax-request's code ? Can't I hook the event, just knowing that it happens warrantly ? (The problem is that request is in the depth of unknown library for me - just I know that data comes via ajax )

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to hide some elements with a specific class, you don't need any JS coding. Just use CSS for this.

```
.myclass { display: none; }
```

Comment: I have to do it only after the event happens anв not merely hide.